# How do I convert an NSNumber to a CLLocation in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am still kind of new to Swift so you'll have to bear with me!

I have gathered my current location coordinates with PFGeoPoint from Parse which are of type NSNumber. I now need to convert them into a CLLocation type so I can use them inside a map view. Can somebody please show me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that it is encoded as an NSNumber? The docs say that it has `latitude` and `longitude` properties that are `double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `CLLocation` instance with:

```
var loc = CLLocation (latitude: <the lat>, longitude: <the lon>)
```

You'll get `<the lat>` and `<the lon>`, both in degrees, from `PFGeoPoint`.